# How to draw energy cycle in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw an energy cycle in `chemfig`.
I would like to get an arrow between C + 1/2O2 to 3CO2, then another one from 4H2 to 4H2O, unfortunately ended with what is in the image. Thanks in advance for technical support.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}%for the \ce command
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\ce{3C(s)+1/2 O2(g)+4H2(g)}\arrow(aa--bb){->[\Delta H_f]}\ce{CH3CH2OH(l)}\arrow(@aa--cc)[-45]\ce{CO2(g)+4H2O(l)}\arrow(@cc--@bb)[45]\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Desired outcome in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}
    %\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{3C{(s)}}
    \+
    \chemfig{\frac{1}{2}O_2{(g)}}
    \+
    \chemfig{4H_2{(g)}}
    \arrow{->[$\Delta Hf$]}
    \chemfig{CH_3CH_2OH{(l)}}
    \arrow(@c1--c3){->[][\chemfig{{+}2O_2}]}[-45,1.7]\chemfig{3CO_2{(g)}}\+\chemfig{4H_2O}
    \arrow(@c2--@c3) {->[][.\chemfig{{+}\frac{9}{2}O_2}]}
    \arrow(@c1.1--@c3){->[*{0}\chemfig{{+}2O_2}]}
    \schemestop 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}%for the \ce command
\begin{document}
%\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\schemestart
\ce{3 C(s) + 1/2 O2(g) + 4 H2(g)}
\arrow{->[ $\Delta H_f$ ]}
\ce{CH3CH2OH(l)}
\arrow(@c1--){0}[-45,1.5]
\ce{CO2(g) + 4 H2O(l)}
\arrow(@c1.195--@c3.170)
\arrow(@c1.350--@c3.20)
\arrow(@c2.200--@c3.10)
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Comment: @Kidegalize Consider to upvote an answer if it was helpful in addition or instead of saying "Thank you".